# I have compilation error when i run my mvc application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, nuget-package

I add Nuget Package Install-Package MvcSiteMapProvider.MVC4 & Install-Package MvcSiteMapProvider.MVC3

Compiler Error Message:

> CS1705:   Assembly 'MvcSiteMapProvider, Version=4.6.18.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1923abe4657913cc' uses
>   'System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' which has a higher version than
>   referenced assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

Comment: Your Package required System.Web.MVC Version 4.0 but in your Projekt there is just version 3.0. You can check if you find an older Version of the Package which supports Version 3.0 of mvc. Best regards, Beat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Right click project
- Click "Unload"
- Right click project
- Click "Edit"
- Search for System.Web.MVC
- Update version to 4.0.0.0
- Save
- Reload Project
- Build

Comment: Now it Showing

**CS0246:**

 The type or namespace name 'MvcSiteMapProvider' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)


`<add namespace="MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.Models" />`

Comment: you need to give the ref of MvcSiteMapProvider to your application! i guess ref is removed @JaydeepChavda

Comment: well you can install nuget package or if you already have dll then right click on Refernece and click on add ref  @JaydeepChavda